# I have duplicate ids because of values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, sas, tidyverse

Ids are duplicated because of multiple types in another column. I would like to remove duplicate ids and have an indicator column for specific types instead. Would be happy to see a solution in R and SAS if possible. Here's what I have and need:

```
have<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6))
have$type<-c("healthy","healthy","injury1","healthy","injury2",
         "injury1","healthy","injury2","healthy","injury2")

need<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
need$injury_ind<-c(0,1,1,0,1,1)
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question. Ids 3 and 5 are both healthy and injured. If this is intentional, I think you need to say more about what the data represents and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we can use `str_detect` (or `grepl`) to detect the 'injury' in 'type' after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
have %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(injury_id = +(any(str_detect(type, 'injury'))))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#     id injury_id
#  <dbl>     <int>
#1     1         0
#2     2         1
#3     3         1
#4     4         0
#5     5         1
#6     6         1
```

We can make the regex a bit more specific by having `'^injury\\d+$'` to match the string 'injury' at the start (`^`) of the string followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(injury_ind = type) ~ id, have,
         FUN = function(x) +(any(grepl('injury', x))))
```

Or without grouping, we can make use of `grepl` to find the 'id's with 'injury' 'type' and check which among the `unique` 'id's are included

```
un1 <- unique(have$id)
data.frame(id = un1, injury_id = +(un1 %in% 
              unique(have$id[grepl('injury', have$type)])))
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the or operator " | " in str_detect()?

Comment: @Tun3In_N0w. Yes, it is possible. `str_detect(type, 'injury|something')`

Comment: I'm trying to get something in dplyr style using str_detect(type, "injury1|injury2")

Comment: @Tun3In_N0w You don't need to do `injury1` `injury2` etc because `str_detect` is matching the substring `injury` and it is giving you the expected output wherever there is `injury`

Comment: @Tun3In_N0w In case you are interested in fixed string match use `%in%` i.e. `summarise(injury_id = +(any(type %in% c('injury1', 'injury2'))))` but this is kind of manual

Comment: @Tun3In_N0w Just to be clear, my point of `|` in `str_detect` is when the substring is totally different

Comment: Thanks that comment is what I needed with %in%. Can you explain what the +(any()) does?

Comment: @Tun3In_N0w `any` as the name suggests it is checking whether there are `any` TRUE elements from the logical output of `str_detect` or `%in%`.  If there is any TRUE, it returns TRUE or else FALSE.  It is coerced to binary 1/0 (TRUE/FALSE) with `+`.  It might be better to use `as.integer` (easier to understand)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I work with a lot of things like this. There aren't many types and they're usually known ahead of time. So, I don't need to text mine for it.